# How to write this query using active record query interface?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I have `products` table with jsonb type `specs` column.
One of the keys in this json is `brand`.

I can successfully run query like this:

`SELECT specs ->> 'brand' AS brand, COUNT(*) FROM products GROUP BY brand;`

```
   brand    | count
-------------+-------
 Acer        |     9
 Dell        |     4
 XPS 15      |     1
 Apple       |     1
 Lenovo      |     2
 Gigabyte    |     1
 Eluktronics |     5
 Asus        |     2
 HP          |     1
```

How can I run this query using active record query interface?

I tried something like:

`Product.select("specs ->> 'brand' AS brand").group('brand').count` but it does not work and I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(specs ->> 'brand' AS brand) AS count_specs_bran...
                                       ^
: SELECT COUNT(specs ->> 'brand' AS brand) AS count_specs_brand_as_brand, brand AS brand FROM "products" GROUP BY brand
        from (irb):1
```

Comment: How about `Product.select("specs ->> 'brand' AS brand, count(*)").group('brand')`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, when I run it and try to get brand of first element with `.first.brand` I get ```ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "products.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ... count(*) FROM "products" GROUP BY brand ORDER BY "products"...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  specs ->> 'brand' AS brand, count(*) FROM "products" GROUP BY brand ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1
        from (irb):14```

Comment: Ok, that's because `first` adds `ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1`. So yep, your answer works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work and sticks more closely to the active record ORM query interface:

```
Product.all.group("specs ->> 'brand'").count
```

You should not include the alias `AS brand`; active record will give its own alias for this  which you can view in the `rails console` after trying out this statement.